# scrollTo delay on page transition effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im working on a page transition that looks like stacked cards. As you scroll down, the card beneath is revealed. But scrolling back up to see previous cards is janky and I can't figure out why. As you quickly scroll back up, the transition effect is seemingly interrupted.

See here for working example:

```js
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
});

$(function(){
 var trueHeight = 0; 
 $('section').each(function() {
  trueHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
  var scrollHeight = trueHeight - $(this).outerHeight();
     $(this).data('offset', scrollHeight);
 });
 
 $('body,html').css({height: trueHeight + "px"});
 
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  
  $('section').each(function() {
   var off = $(this).data('offset');
   if (scrollTop > off) {
    var translate =  (scrollTop - off) / $(window).height() * 100;
    $(this).css({transform: 'translateY(' + -translate +'%)'});
   }
  });
  
 });
});
```

```css
/* Welcome to Compass.
 * In this file you should write your main styles. (or centralize your imports)
 * Import this file using the following HTML or equivalent:
 * <link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

html {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle; }

q, blockquote {
  quotes: none; }
  q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    content: "";
    content: none; }

a img {
  border: none; }

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block; }

html {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: inherit; }

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative; }

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 22.652px;
  z-index: 999; }

h1 {
  margin-top: 48%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 22.652px; }

.copy {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.35765%;
  width: 65.88078%;
  margin-left: 34.11922%; }
  .copy:last-child {
    margin-right: 0; }

.container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden; }

section {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 735px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); }

#hero {
  background: #bada55;
  z-index: 99; }

#project1 {
  background: #54d9d5;
  z-index: 98; }

#project2 {
  background: #e49012;
  z-index: 97; }

#project3 {
  background: #545fd9;
  z-index: 96; }

#project4 {
  background: #e312cb;
  z-index: 95; }

#project5 {
  background: #d95454;
  z-index: 94; }

#project6 {
  background: #e3dd12;
  z-index: 93; }
```

```html
<body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
  <div class="container">
         <section id="hero">
          <div class="copy">
           <h1>Hello There</h1>
          </div>
         </section>
         <section id="project1">
          <div class="copy">
           <h1>Hello There</h1>
          </div>
         </section>
         <section id="project2">
          <div class="copy">
           <h1>Hello There</h1>
          </div>
         </section>
         <section id="project3">
          <div class="copy">
           <h1>Hello There</h1>
          </div>
         </section>
         <section id="project4">
          <div class="copy">
           <h1>Hello There</h1>
          </div>
         </section>
         <section id="project5">
          <div class="copy">
           <h1>Hello There</h1>
          </div>
         </section>
         <section id="project6">
          <div class="copy">
           <h1>Hello There</h1>
          </div>
         </section>                  
  </div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>


    </body>
```

I am guessing either my math is off or that jquery cannot handle quick scrolling. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this does the trick:

```
    $('section').each(function() {
        var off = $(this).data('offset');
        if (scrollTop > off) {
            var translate = (off - scrollTop) / $(window).height() * 100;
            $(this).css({transform: 'translateY(' + translate +'%)'});
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({transform: 'translateY(' + 0 + '%)'});
        }
    });
```

Adding the else statement solved my problem. Without it, the `<section>`'s didn't know when to stop translating. The math is such that var translate would never actually hit zero if the user scrolled quickly.

Comment: Please add also a few words on how/why that helped.